# Showing Bootstrap Timepicker on Focus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using jdewit's Bootstrap-Timepicker and there is an appended icon that triggers the appearance of the timepicker. My users are complaining and asking that the timepicker appear when the field received focus. There is no mention in the documentation so I was hoping someone would know how to achieve this.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><html class="fixIE no-js"><![endif]-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>CMS - Create Assignment</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.edrpo.com/assets/bootstrap-time-picker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" media="screen,print" />

<script src="http://www.edrpo.com/assets/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>  <script src="http://www.edrpo.com/assets/js/modernizr.js"></script> <script src="http://www.edrpo.com/assets/js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js"></script>    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.edrpo.com/assets/bootstrap-time-picker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wholePage">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <div id="header">
             <a href="http://www.edrpo.com/webster/prop_home" title="Logo">
                    <img src="http://www.edrpo.com/assets/images/banner.png" border="0" alt="WEBster Logo"/>
                 </a>
     </div> <!--END header DIV-->

<div id="mainContentHome">

        <div id="theEditor">
            <h2 style="font:bold 16px Verdana; color:#076324;padding-left:70px;">
                NEW RESIDENT STAFF ASSIGNMENT
            </h2>
            <br><br>
            <div id="frmAddAssignment" style="width:70%;margin-left:80px;padding:20px 0px 20px 100px;border:2px solid #076324;">
                                <form action="http://www.edrpo.com/staffer/create_assignment_handler" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="frmAddAss">              
<input type="hidden" name="propNumber" value="300" />
                <label for="location">Assignment Location:</label>
                <select name="location" style="width:80%;">
<option value="0">Please Select ...</option>
<option value="4">Arena Conceirge</option>
<option value="5">Launch Room</option>
<option value="1">President's Mansion</option>
<option value="2">Training Center Front Desk</option>
</select>               <br><br>
                                <label for="day">Assignment Day:</label>
                <select name="day" style="width:80%;">
<option value="-">Please Select ...</option>
<option value="0">Sunday</option>
<option value="1">Monday</option>
<option value="2">Tuesday</option>
<option value="3">Wednesday</option>
<option value="4">Thursday</option>
<option value="5">Friday</option>
<option value="6">Saturday</option>
</select>               <br><br>
                <label for="start">Assignment Start Time:</label>
                <div id="tmStart" class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
                    <input type="text" id="txStart" name="start">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <label for="duration">Duration (in hours): Use can enter ".5" for a half hour (6.5)</label>
                <input type="text" name="duration" value="" style="width:78%;" />               <br><br>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </div> <!-- END ajaxAddArtist DIV -->
                <br><br>
            <p style='text-align:center;'><input type="image" name="submit" value="" src="http://www.edrpo.com/assets/images/create.png"  /></p>        </div><!-- END theEditor DIV -->
        <div id="footer"> <hr style='width:85%;color:#cdcdcd;' /><img src="http://www.edrtrust.com/images/siteAssets/logo.png" alt=""/><br /><br /><a href='mailto:jgravois@edrtrust.com;lwassmer@edrtrust.com'>Email the Web Team</a> </div> <!--END footer DIV-->
    </div> <!--END wholePage DIV-->

<script>
    (function() {
        $('#txStart').timepicker();
    })(); // end self-invoking anonymous function
</script>
<script>
    $("#txStart").on("focus", function() {
        return $(this).timepicker("showWidget");
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event listener to the input field and then fire `showWidget` on you timepicker. Add this before `</body>` in your HTML file:

```
<script>
  $("#txStart").on("focus", function() {
    return $(this).timepicker("showWidget");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Another problem has surfaced. Now the timepicker won't close on tab or enter and when I click away from the widget, the current time is entered into the input rather than the time entered via the time picker. Would that be a result of our code change???  (BTW, I updated my code in the question to reflect your response.)

Comment: I don't fully get what you mean. When you click Enter while having the field focused your form is submitted which is a normal behavior of form. Do you want the timepicker to disappear once you switch to the next input field by pressing Tab? When I click away from the widget the time is entered which I have set with the timepicker. Or do I understand you wrong? Here the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gW7VJ/

Comment: The way it is now, the widget shows when the input gets focus or when the clokc icon is clicked -- that is what I was after at the beginning. BUT now I enter a time of 3:30PM in the widget. To close the widget, I have to click somewhere else on the page and when I do, the time has reverted back to 02:00PM which is what it was before I made the edit. "Enter" submitting the form is the normal action for a form and that is OK with me. The problem I am having is closing the widget and having it keep the updated time.

Comment: And yes, to answer your question better, I want a third tab ( click to open, tab to minutes, tab to meridian, tab to close ) to dismiss the widget AND keep the updated time.

Comment: I just noticed that I posted the wrong link. THIS is the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/gW7VJ/1/ . Clicking on input field opens widget. clicking on arrows in widget updates field correctly. Clicking outside of the input field updates time in widget. Opening widget again shows correct time. updating widget when typing in input field seems not possible: http://jsfiddle.net/gW7VJ/2/ . Closing the widget when pressing tab can be achieved like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gW7VJ/3/ . generally changing the behavior of a plugin is problematic in most cases like this case shows :)